# Good database design for bilingual site: booleans vs meta tables?

Tags: database, database-design, multilingual

I'm making a site with listings of game music concerts. It will be both in English and Japanese.

Concerts take place at a venue. I want to store data about the venue's name and address in English and Japanese. I also want to allow storing alternative names for them e.g. "Konserthuset" and "Stockholm Concert Hall". The former is the name in Swedish. The fact that the language is Swedish, isn't important to store in the database. But if would be Japanese, I want that stored.

So one venue can have multiple addresses and names. Cities and countries don't need anymore than two fields (and id), the English name and the Japanese name.

Option 1:

```
table Venue
  id (pk)
  cityId
  description

table VenueName
  venueID (fk)
  name
  IsJapanese (boolean)

table VenueAddress
  venueID (fk)
  address
  IsJapanese (boolean)

table City
  id (pk)
  name
  japaneseName
  countryId (fk)

table Country
  id (pk)
  name
  JapaneseName
```

---

Option 2:

```
 Venue
   id (pk)

 Information
   venueID (fk)
   infoTypeID (fk)
   text

 InfoType
   id (pk)
   name
```

This is what I mean by meta table (correct term?). Quite flexible but I wonder how the queries will be. Examples of InfoTypes could be EngName, JpnName, EngAddress, JpnAddress, EngCity, JpnCity, etc.

---

I know there are many other ways I could build the database. Are either of these good database designing? What better solution do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is fine, if you are doing this as an exercise.  But Option 2 is much more flexible in the long run--for instance, when you decide that you want to represent the venue name in German, or Russian, or Mandarin.